# Shadow map weird results

Tags: math, graphics, glm

So, I am right now i a way to implement shadow mapping and I stuck with the issue, which is when I move, shadows are being changing.

At first I got simple shadow mapping with which there was no change when camera moved. Then I implemented cascaded shadow mapping and there started all the fun: first, when I implemented it, there was such an issue: when I move the shadows would change. Then I tried to implement stable csm(used bounding sphere and texel-based displacement instead of pixel-based), but the issue is still remains(I thought stable csm whould fix it). I am using NearZ=0.01 and FarZ=100(and I get frustum splits like 0.01, 3.527), (3.527, 10.844), (10.844, 100.0)), so I thought it would be z-fighting, but, I guess, it is not z-fighting at all.

This is my light code snippets, but I am providing just in case if it is even will be needed.
This is how I geenrate my matrices but at most this looks fine. But I believe, maybe, the issue could be in generating light perspective

```
glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(-4, 4, 2);
glm::vec3 lightDir = glm::normalize(-lightPos);
glm::mat4 cameraView    = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraDir, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
glm::mat4 cameraPersp   = glm::perspectiveRH_ZO(70.0, 1240.0 / 720.0, 0.001, 100.0);
glm::mat4 cameraInverse = glm::inverse(cameraPersp * cameraView);

std::vector<glm::vec4> cameraCorners = 
{
    // Near
    glm::vec4{-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    glm::vec4{ 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    glm::vec4{ 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    glm::vec4{-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    // Far
    glm::vec4{-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    glm::vec4{ 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    glm::vec4{ 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    glm::vec4{-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
};

for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cameraCorners[i] = cameraInverse * cameraCorners[i];
    cameraCorners[i] = cameraCorners[i] / cameraCorners[i].w;
}

glm::vec3 center(0);
for(glm::vec3 V : cameraCorners)
{
    center += V;
}
center /= 8.0;
float radius = 0.0f;
for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    float dist = glm::length(glm::vec3(cameraCorners[i]) - center);
    radius = Max(radius, dist);
}
radius = std::ceil(radius);

glm::mat4 lightView = glm::lookAt(center - lightDir, center, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

glm::vec3 maxExt = center + radius;
glm::vec3 minExt = center - radius;
maxExt = lightView * glm::vec4(maxExt, 1.0);
minExt = lightView * glm::vec4(minExt, 1.0);
glm::mat4 lightProj = glm::orthoRH_ZO(minExt.x, maxExt.x, minExt.y, maxExt.y, minExt.z, maxExt.z);
```

[There is a gif for an issue visualization](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J17p-oedkCGcKQohpi-j67QK9iDko7YS/view?usp=drivesdk).
Thanks in advance